# sir i'm trying to add image resourse in recycler view programatically runtime but doesnt getting valid output

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

in this code required condition setting  proper image . but further next  recylerView adapter position Imageview  also set image resourse without any .... condition. sorry for poor english but help me ... somebody

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull View_holder holder, int position) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Cursor cursor =database.query("FAVORITE_TABLE",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            arr.add(cursor.getInt(0));
        }
        if(arr.contains(position)){
            holder.img_favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should always set image background otherwise it will use previous holder data.
so you should have default image background which can be set in case there is no desired background. try below your code snippet using 
some default_background resource.

```
if(arr.contains(position)){
  holder.img_favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
} else {
  holder.img_favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_background);
}
```